# How to count the relations between names in the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, combinatorics

I have a table called `names` with rows consisting of a name and a group for that name.

I want to count how much times any two names appear together in any group.

**Table**

```
name    | group
--------+------
Renato  |   1
John    |   1 
Paul    |   1
Renato  |   2
John    |   2
John    |   3
Paul    |   3
```

**Expected result**

```
name 1  | name 2 |count
--------+--------+-----
Renato  | John   |  2
Renato  | Paul   |  1
John    | Renato |  2 
John    | Paul   |  2
Paul    | Renato |  1
Paul    | John   |  2
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Examples of your data and expected results would help with visualizing what you mean.

Comment: @Oded Yes, i added some data and expected result.

Comment: Why do you have `name 1` and `name 2` in the results? That doesn't match up with your description.

Comment: @Oded I want to count how much times two names appears in the same group together, in this case, Renato appears with John in Group 1 and 2.

Comment: Your results appear to violate [the principle of orthogonal design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design) i.e. the tuple `{ 'John' ,  'Paul' ,  2 }` represents the same proposition as the tuple `{ 'Paul', 'John' ,  2 }`. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @onedaywhen Maybe, this will be used for data visualization and discovery, so I think use in this way will let the things more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT n1.name AS "name 1", n2.name AS "name 2",
    COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM "names" AS n1
JOIN "names" AS n2
    ON n1.group = n2.group
WHERE n1.name <> n2.name
GROUP BY n1.name, n2.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  lefttbl.name as name_1,
  righttbl.name as name_2,
  count(*) as together_count
FROM
  xx AS lefttbl
  INNER JOIN xx AS righttbl on lefttbl.group=righttbl.group
WHERE lefttbl.name<>righttbl.name
GROUP BY name_1,name_2
;
```

Gives you the desired structure. I updated the SQL to remove the need for quotes, as to satisfy those, who are able to correctly identify a quoting incompatibility, but unwilling to correct it.

Comment: Feel free to edit it - I guess you refer to the backticks for the field quotes.